# How to Set Product Count in Magento Custom Module?

Tags: magento, count, product

Hi I've been trying for hours to simply set how many products are display in a best seller module. No luck!

I've searched and have not found an answer on the web for this particular problem.

This site http://www.jimcode.org/2011/04/magento-setting-columns-limiting-products-shown-grid/ comes close but I'm just not getting it.

Here's "my" code:

```
<?php if($this->getItemCollection() && $this->getItemCollection()->getSize()): ?>
<div class="block">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Top Sellers In This Category') ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
    <?php  $this->setColumnCount(1); // uncomment this line if you want to have another number of columns ?>
    <?php $this->resetItemsIterator() ?>
    <?php for($_i=0;$_i<$this->getRowCount();$_i++): ?>
        <tr>
        <?php for($_j=0;$_j<$this->getColumnCount();$_j++): ?>
            <?php if($_link=$this->getIterableItem()): ?>
                            <div class="img" style="float:left;width:212px">
                                <a href="<?php echo $_link->getProductUrl() ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_link, 'small_image')->constrainOnly(TRUE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(193); ?>" width="193" height="" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_link->getName()) ?>" /></a>                                                                          
                            </div>
                            <div class="text" style="float:left;width:212px;margin-top:-60px"><img  style="width:45px;height:64px;position:relative;z-index:15;right:0px;bottom:260px" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/ribbon.png'); ?>" />
                                <div class="title"><a href="<?php echo $_link->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_link->getName()) ?></a></div>
                                No: <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_link->getSku()) ?>
                                <div class="price"></div>
                                <a href="<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_link) ?>" class="arr">Add to Cart</a>
                            </div>
                <?php else: ?>
                <td class="empty-product">&nbsp;</td>
                <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endfor; ?>
        </tr>
<?php
/*        <?php if($_i+2<=$this->getRowCount()): ?>
            <tr>
                <td class="spacer" colspan="6"><div class="separatorsmall"></div></td>
            </tr>
          <?php endif; ?>
*/
?>    <?php endfor; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the size of the collection to e.g. 40 by adding `$this->getItemCollection()->getSelect()->limit(40)`.

Comment: I tried adding your suggestion like this: if($this->getItemCollection() && $this->getItemCollection()->getSelect()->limit(3)): but it didn't make any difference. I've tried setting the Limit in the XML ...made no difference either. It's strange, like it has a mind. I've tried a dozen different things a nothing. Isn't there global setting!? Like singleton?